# Why does BOOST_TEST((Iterator == Iterator)) require extra parentheses?

Tags: c++, boost

I am testing my implementation of binary search from `binsearch.hpp`:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
Iterator binsearch(Iterator begin, Iterator end, const T &v) {
    if (std::distance(begin, end) == 0) {return end;}

    Iterator save = end;

    while (std::distance(begin, end) > 0) {
        Iterator mid = begin + std::distance(begin, end) / 2;

        if (*mid == v) {
            return mid;
        }

        if (v < *mid) {
            end = mid;
        } else {
            begin = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return save;
}
```

with the following boost-driven unit test `test_binsearch.cpp`:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test_binsearch
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "binsearch.hpp"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(empty_0) {
    std::vector<int> xs = {};

    const auto result = binsearch(xs.begin(), xs.end(), 42);

    BOOST_TEST((result == xs.end()));
}
```

Unless I surround the comparison inside the `BOOST_TEST` with an extra pair of parentheses, I get a very cryptic and long compilation error that repeatedly tries to convert an iterator to a char, an error code and a few other types:

> note:   cannot convert ‘t’ (type ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator std::vector >’) to type ‘char’
>
> ```
>     ostr << t;
> ```

I got the clue to surround my comparison with extra parentheses [from here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/boost_test_universal_macro.html). Why does it fail to compile without them?

Comment: parentheses missing from the macro?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath maybe, I am not that good with macros. However, simple things like `BOOST_TEST(0 == 0)` work without the extra parens.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's going on in their source, but they use some overloaded `operator<<` on the macro's argument (without parens) and `<<` having higher precedence than `==` screws things up.

Comment: Try `std::cout << result;` (or `std::cout << xs.end();`) and I suspect you'll get a similar error.

Comment: @jv_ yes, the error is exactly the same. Can't we print iterators in c++? That is strange imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/boost_test_universal_macro.html#boost_test.testing_tools.boost_test_universal_macro.complex_statements) of BOOST_TEST:

> ### Complex statements
>
> BOOST_TEST provides an enhanced reporting capability: **additional details of
>   the failing operands and operations are provided in the log**, as shown on the
>   example below:
>
> *Example: BOOST_TEST enhanced reporting* (**reduced version**)
>
> **Code**
>
> ```
> #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE boost_test_macro3
> #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
>
> BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( mytest )
> {
>   int a = 13, b = 12;
>   BOOST_TEST(a - 1 < b);
> }
> ```

**Output**

> ```
> > ./boost_test_macro3 --log_level=all
> Running 1 test case...
> Entering test module "boost_test_macro3"
> test.cpp(12): Entering test case "mytest"
> test.cpp(17): error: in "mytest": check a - 1 < b has failed [13 - 1 >= 12]
>                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>                                                               !!!  sic !!!
> ...
> ```

Pay attention to the emphasized fragment of the test failure report. For those with moderate conduct of C++ it may seem like magic (newbies don't get surprised since they are not aware of the limitations of the language; experts know the secret or figure it out easily).

The documentation superficially explains the "magic" as follows:

> BOOST_TEST **parses the statement** and constructs an expression out of it.

However, the "magic" doesn't work with types that cannot be "printed to an `std::ostream`". Hence your compilation error. Fortunately the "magic" (which is based on operator overloading) cannot override C++ rules of operator precedence. By adding the extra pair of parentheses you define the territory where the "magic" cannot reach.